# Why does IdHTTPProxyServer change the HTTP version of requests?

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

Recently, I found that IdHTTPProxyServer automatically changes all HTTP/1.1 requests to HTTP/1.0 requests. It is a little bit weird for me as I think a proxy server should not change the HTTP version. Is there any way I can force the proxy server to not change HTTP version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TIdHTTPProxyServer` does not support HTTP 1.1 at this time.  The behavior that changes the HTTP version is hard-coded, as `TIdHTTPProxyServer` is not actually passing through the client's request as-is, but is sending its own HTTP 1.0 request that contains the client's requested data in it.  The only way you can change that is to edit `IdHTTPProxyServer.pas` and then recompile Indy.